# Give an example of a symmetric $3x3$ matrix that is not diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Give an example of a symmetric $3x3$ matrix that is not diagonal.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    2 &4 & 4 \\
    4 &8 & 8 \\
    4 & 8&8 
\end{pmatrix}=A $$ and $$ A^{T}=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 &4 & 4 \\
    4 &8 & 8 \\
    4 & 8&8 
\end{pmatrix}$$
so $$ A = A^{T} $$ i.e. $A$ is symmetric. Upon reducing A to it's canonical form we have $$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 &2 & 2 \\
    0 &0 & 0 \\
    0 &0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore $A$ is symmetric and not diagonal. So it appears that in general any symmetric matrix that has rows that are duplicates or possibly scalar multiples are not diagonal?

Comment: What does being diagonal have to do with the canonical form?

Comment: Do you mean diagonalizable?

Comment: A diagonal matrix is one that has all entries zero except the diagonal. I supposed that a matrix is determined to be diagonal by performing row reduction if it has that form after the row reduction.

Comment: No, a matrix is diagonal if it is diagonal before doing anything to it. A matrix is diagonalizable if you can apply a *similarity transformation* to make it diagonal. But row reduction is not a similarity transformation. (If it were, eigenvalues would be far easier to find and therefore also roots of polynomials would be far easier to find).

Comment: Well thank you Ian. The question does not ask to find a matrix that is symmetric and not diagonalizable. It would make more sense if that were the case it seems.

Comment: If that were the case then the spectral theorem would tell you that there is no such answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 &4 & 4 \\
    4 &8 & 8 \\
    4 & 8&8 
\end{pmatrix} $$
Is not diagonal.

But it can be diagonalized, as any symmetric matrix:

$$A=PDP^{-1}$$
with:
$$ D = \begin{pmatrix}
    0 &0 & 0 \\
    0 &0 & 0 \\
    0 &0 &18 
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad P=\begin{pmatrix}
    -2 &-2 & 1 \\
    0 &1 & 2 \\
    1 &0 &12 
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad P^{-1}=\frac{1}{9}\begin{pmatrix}
    -2 &-4 & 5 \\
    -2 &5 & -4 \\
    1 &2 &2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and note that the columns of $P$ are orthogonal vectors.

This is the  ''canonical'' or ''[normal Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form)'' of the matrix $A$

Comment: Right. Thank you. Reduced row echelon form is also a canonical form. So, it appears that while it is there infinitely many examples of symmetric matrices that are not diagonal there are no symmetric matrices that are not diagonalizable.

Comment: Yes, **reduced row echelon form**  is also called **row canonical** form, and obviously there are infinitely many symmetric matrix that are not diagonal and can be reduced to anon diagonal **reduced row echelon form**, but note that the **row canonical** form is not given by a similarity transformation, but the **jordan form** is.